# function taking 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, discord.py

Looked at other answers but none seem relevant to mine

I am getting an error telling me my function is recieving two positional arguments instead of one and I cannot figure out how this is happening as ctx is the only arguement

Code:

```py
@commands.command()
  async def join(self, ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
      await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel.\nJoin one to use me!")
    voice_channel= ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await voice_channel.connect()
      await ctx.send("Hello!")
      self.musiccontrols(ctx)
    else:
      await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
      self.musiccontrols(ctx)
```

```py
async def musiccontrols(ctx):
    newmusicchannel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel("{}'s Music Controls".format(ctx.author.voice.channel))
    songthumbnail = info['thumbnail']
    songembed=discord.Embed(title="{}'s Music Controls".format(ctx.author.voice.channel), description="", color=000000)
    songembed.set_image(url=songthumbnail)
    if queue is None:
      nowplaying = "Nothing is playing"
    else:
      nowplaying = queue[0]
    songembed.add_field(name="Now Playing:", value=nowplaying, inline=False)
    await newmusicchannel.send(embed=musiccontrolsembed)
```

Error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: musiccontrols() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
//above referencing line where 
[if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await voice_channel.connect()
      await ctx.send("Hello!")
      self.musiccontrols(ctx)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things wrong here:

1. You're missing `self`
2. You're not `await`ing the coroutine

```py
async def musiccontrols(self, ctx):
    ...
```

```py
await self.musiccontrols(ctx)
```

Comment: I hope you dont mind if I ask 1 more question regarding classes:
Im getting an error in the same class (``NameError: name 'queue' is not defined``)
Despite defining it as a list?
Code:
https://pastebin.com/7h0PJ4VN

Comment: `self.queue`, though you should define it inside the `__init__` method (`self.queue = []`)

Comment: tysm for the answer - can you just not put variables and lists not in a function outside init?

Comment: I guess you can, but you should do it in the global scope (before or after the class definition), these are known as `global variables`, when setting variables in the `__init__` method (or any other class method) they're called `instance variables`. Maybe try learning a bit more about classes.

Comment: so sorry im still getting 1 error:
https://pastebin.com/Lkq0pWrx

Comment: The list is empty and you're trying to access the first value (doesn't exist -- throws `IndexError`)

Answer (score 0):

The fact you call `musiccontrols` as `self.musiccontrols(ctx)` suggests `musiccontrols` is a class method. In which case the first argument of every class method is a reference to the class itself. So try changing `async def musiccontrols(ctx):` to `async def musiccontrols(self, ctx):`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this is a class method.

Python implicitly passes `self` to the class method.

So your call:

```py
self.musiccontrols(ctx)
```

Actually gets turned into:

```py
musiccontrols(self, ctx)
```

That's why Python complains about two arguments being passed.

The fix is to change your function definition to:

```py
async def musiccontrols(self, ctx):
```